# Сериализация не сохраняет настройки

Tags: c#

```
 public static void SerializationItemTable(TreeTable treeTable)
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            //string fileName = "saveTable10.dat";
            string fileName = @"D:\Progect Visual Studio 2010\Tree.Inventory\Tree.Inventory\bin\Debug\saveTable10.dat";
            using (Stream s = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(s, treeTable);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException) { }

        catch (SerializationException) { }

    }

 public static TreeTable DeserializationItemTable()
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            TreeTable table = null;
            //string fileName = "saveTable10.dat";
            string fileName = @"D:\Progect Visual Studio 2010\Tree.Inventory\Tree.Inventory\bin\Debug\saveTable10.dat";
            using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                table = (TreeTable)formatter.Deserialize(s);
            }

            return table;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Когда меняю путь для сериализации на "saveTable10.dat" файл создается но при  десериализации не сохранились.
Класс реализует интерфейс ISerialization в нем находится коллекция вот она и не сохраняется

```
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("foto", listFoto, typeof(Collection<string>));
    }

    protected TreeFoto(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        listFoto = (Collection<string>)info.GetValue("foto", typeof(Collection<string>));
    }
```

Comment: Скорей всего вы просто указываете разный путь при сериализации/десериализации. Но кода очень мало приведено, чтобы сказать точнее. (Поэтому вас народ и минусует.)

Comment: ок, подскажите чем отличается если я указываю путь"File.dat" от @"D:\Progect Visual Studio 2010\Tree.Inventory\Tree.Inventory\bin\Debug\File.dat". Если укаазываю путь "File.dat" настройки при сериализации не сохраняются, а при сохранении "@"D:\Progect Visual Studio 2010\Tree.Inventory\Tree.Inventory\bin\Debug\File.dat"  сохраняются

Comment: "при десериализации не сохранились" - имелось в виду, при десериализации объект не восстанавливается ?

Comment: да при десериализации обьект не восстанавливается

Comment: стоп, обьект  восстанавливается  но коллекция которая сериализируется пустая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Содержимое папки bin меняется при каждом билдинге проекта, в том числе и файлы ресурсов это как-бы очевидно.

Сделаю предположение, что Tree.Inventory, это отделная сборка, возможно dll, а используете вы ее в другом проекте. Если это так, то при сохранении в @"D:\Progect Visual Studio 2010\Tree.Inventory\Tree.Inventory\bin\Debug\File.dat" файл будет существовать до тех пор пока вы не внесете изменения в сам Tree.Inventory. А при сохранении @"File.dat" файл сохраняется непосредственно в папку bin\Debug вашего конечного проекта, который соответственно постоянно "чистится". Если File.dat добавлен в проект, то можно сделать следующий "финт ушами":

1. В свойствах этого файла установить "Не копировать"
2. Вручную скопировать скопировать этот файл в папки bin\Debug и bin\Release

Тогда при компиляции файл меняться не будет и у вас программа должна заработать.

P.S. Мои предположения могут быть и ошибочны, ошибок разных много, это только один из вариантов, ИМХО более вероятный.

Comment: Спасибо помогло